# double click on nodes in cytoscape.js is not working

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a problem with this plugin. I want to double click on nodes and the id of nodes should be displayed in console. I added the link of this extension from https://github.com/fixpoint/cytoscape-dblclick and followed by this post [Cytoscape js - Call a function whenever a node is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58322873/cytoscape-js-call-a-function-whenever-a-node-is-clicked), but still is not working.
Is anybody have any idea why it is not working, it would be nice if you share it.
You can see my code:

```js
$(function() {

  var elements = {
    nodes: [

    ],
    edges: [

    ]
  };

  function randomNumber(a) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (a));
  }
  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    ready: function() {},
    style: [{
        selector: "node", //edge
        style: {
          content: "data(id)",
          shape: "roundrectangle", //square, circle

          "text-valign": "center",
          "text-halign": "center",
          height: "60px", //new
          width: "100px", //new
          //padding: "10px", //new
          "text-wrap": 'wrap', //new
          color: "#fff",
          "background-color": "#11479e",
          //   "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
        }
      },

      {
        //arrows
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "taxi",
          //'background-color': '#008000',
          width: 4,
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "line-color": "#9dbaea",
          "target-arrow-color": "#9dbaea"
        }
      }
    ],
  });


  cy.dblclick();
  cy.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
    console.log('dblclick');
    cy.animate({
      fit: {
        eles: evt.target,
        padding: 10,
      },
    });
  });
  cy.on('dblclick:timeout', function(evt) {
    console.log('dblclick:timeout');
  });

  var ab = 12;
  for (var i = 0; i < ab; i++) {
    //elements.nodes.push({ "data": { "id": i } });
    cy.add([{
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: i
        }
      }

    ])
  }
  var cb = 20;
  for (var i = 0; i < cb; i++) {
    cy.add([{
      group: "edges",
      data: {
        source: randomNumber(ab),
        target: randomNumber(ab)
      }
    }])
  }
  cy.layout({
    name: "dagre", //dagre, grid
    directed: true,
    nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true,
    boxSelectionEnabled: true,
    autounselectify: true,
    zoomingEnabled: true,
    userZoomingEnabled: true,
    styleEnabled: true
  }).run();



  cy.elements().qtip({
    content: function() {
      return 'Text, Test ' + this.id()
    },
    position: {
      my: 'center left', //top center
      at: 'center right' //bottom center
    },
    style: {
      classes: 'qtip-bootstrap', //qtip-dark
      tip: {
        width: 16,
        height: 10

      }
    }
  });
  //  });

}); //end
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
  <title>cytoscape-panzoom.js demo</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <link href="cytoscape.js-panzoom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src="https://js.cytoscape.org/js/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cpettitt/dagre/v0.7.4/dist/dagre.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
  <!-- qtip Links -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/2.7.0/cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>

  <!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
  <!-- <script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script> -->

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-dblclick/dist/index.js"></script>
  <script src="cytoscape-panzoom.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="cy"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So are you trying to console.log the ID of the double clicked node? You are currently logging the string `"dblclick"` and then fitting the graph to the node. You could simply log evt.target.id(), just like in the linked post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the post you already linked and log the node information instead of fitting the graph to the clicked node. Also, your demo had some static scripts in the header, I removed them for that reason. That way, the qtip works again too:

```js
$(function() {

  var elements = {
    nodes: [

    ],
    edges: [

    ]
  };

  function randomNumber(a) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (a));
  }
  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),

    ready: function() {},
    style: [{
        selector: "node", //edge
        style: {
          content: "data(id)",
          shape: "roundrectangle", //square, circle

          "text-valign": "center",
          "text-halign": "center",
          height: "60px", //new
          width: "100px", //new
          //padding: "10px", //new
          "text-wrap": 'wrap', //new
          color: "#fff",
          "background-color": "#11479e",
          //   "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
        }
      },

      {
        //arrows
        selector: "edge",
        style: {
          "curve-style": "taxi",
          //'background-color': '#008000',
          width: 4,
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "line-color": "#9dbaea",
          "target-arrow-color": "#9dbaea"
        }
      }
    ],
  });


  cy.dblclick();
  cy.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.id());
  });

  var ab = 12;
  for (var i = 0; i < ab; i++) {
    //elements.nodes.push({ "data": { "id": i } });
    cy.add([{
        group: "nodes",
        data: {
          id: i
        }
      }

    ])
  }
  var cb = 20;
  for (var i = 0; i < cb; i++) {
    cy.add([{
      group: "edges",
      data: {
        source: randomNumber(ab),
        target: randomNumber(ab)
      }
    }])
  }
  cy.layout({
    name: "dagre", //dagre, grid
    directed: true,
    nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true,
    boxSelectionEnabled: true,
    autounselectify: true,
    zoomingEnabled: true,
    userZoomingEnabled: true,
    styleEnabled: true
  }).run();



  cy.elements().qtip({
    content: function() {
      return 'Text, Test ' + this.id()
    },
    position: {
      my: 'center left', //top center
      at: 'center right' //bottom center
    },
    style: {
      classes: 'qtip-bootstrap', //qtip-dark
      tip: {
        width: 16,
        height: 10

      }
    }
  });
  //  });

}); //end
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#cy {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
  <title>cytoscape-panzoom.js demo</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <!--<link href="cytoscape.js-panzoom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
  <!--<link href="font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src="https://js.cytoscape.org/js/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cpettitt/dagre/v0.7.4/dist/dagre.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
  <!-- qtip Links -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/2.7.0/cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>

  <!-- for testing with local version of cytoscape.js -->
  <!-- <script src="../cytoscape.js/build/cytoscape.js"></script> -->

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-dblclick/dist/index.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="cytoscape-panzoom.js"></script>-->

</head>

<body>

  <div id="cy"></div>


</body>

</html>
```